# Implementation of the nerve of a category in GAP

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, gap

I am trying to compute the second cohomology group of the coset poset $$\mathcal{C}_G\mathcal{F}=\{gA\mid g\in G,A\in\mathcal{F}\}$$ for a finite group $G$ and a family $\mathcal{F}$ of subgroups of $G$. In a broader sense, I am dealing with functors $$F:P\to\mathbf{Ab},$$ where $P$ is a poset of either subgroups or cosets of subgroups of a given group, and trying to compute some higher limits.

GAP is for sure the best software for group theory, and I am aware of the existence of the package CAP for categories, but I was not able to find examples of how to input a category with this package. My first goal is to compute the invariants $${H^2(\mathcal{C}_G\mathcal{F},k)}^G$$ for some finite group $G$ and field $k$. For this purpose, it would be nice to find the way to input $\mathcal{C}_G\mathcal{F}$ (as a category) in GAP (the hardest part to me), then to define its nerve/simplicial complex (this should be easier), the rest is just algebraic topology and there are packages for that. Once this is done, the more general case $F:P\to\mathbf{Ab}$ would follow a similar idea.

Any suggestion? Maybe an example with an easy poset/category. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd contest the statement that "GAP is for sure the best software for group theory". Magma is at the very least a serious contender, but it's not free.

Comment: @DaveBenson you are right, I was just considering free softwares for my claim. Btw, do you think Magma is better for this problem in particular? I did not try it, to be honest.

Comment: Sorry, never tried that sort of computation. But it does do quite well at low degree cohomology computations.  If you can write it as Ext over a finite dimensional algebra, it will certainly do the computation.